# How can I return a WebGL camera's position in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, 3d, webgl, p5.js

I'm trying to make a program with a first-person camera in a 3D space with p5.js's WebGL canvas context. Currently, I'm working on implementing camera rotation ("tilt" and "pan"), and I have an issue where the camera inverts as it approaches a certain point. I want to be able to add logic to prevent that. Although, to do that, I first need to find a way to get the camera's tilt at a given point in time.

This is the code I have that manages the camera and the canvas:

```
let cam;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(displayWidth, displayHeight, WEBGL);
  cam = createCamera();
}

function draw() {
  // assume camera position is updated here..
}
```

This is the code I have for camera movement:

```
function mouseMoved(e) {
  // To make sure "cam" has loaded and been defined as a p5.Camera
  if (cam instanceof p5.Camera) {

    // H = horizontal, V = vertical
    let camAngH = -e.movementX / 5;
    let camAngV = e.movementY / 15;

    cam.pan(camAngH);
    cam.tilt(camAngV);
  }
}
```

I have read their documentation and looked through all the p5.Camera methods, and I haven't been able to find anything about my problem specifically. If you know anything about this, it would be awesome if you could give me any tips or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.